# how to Styling classes with the same name in a file css

Tags: css

i have one problem .I can not give each one a particular style.help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwMe6.png)

Comment: dont post images. Please paste the code into code snippet and post it in your question

Comment: Please put some more effort in explaining your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:nth-of-type(n)` selector.

// For First Right Class Div

```
#container .right:nth-of-type(1) {

}
```

// For First Left Class Div

```
#container .left:nth-of-type(1) {

}
```

Hence for every div you need to change n value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear but I want to help you out anyhow. I assume you want to style each div inside the container individually, rather than styling all of ".left" and ".right".

To do this, you can add multiple classes to each div;

```css
.right {
  color: red;
}

.left {
  color: blue;
}

.r1,
.l3{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='right r1'>r1</div>
  <div class='right r2'>r2</div>
  <div class='right r3'>r3</div>
  <div class='right r4'>r4</div>
  <div class='left l1'>l1</div>
  <div class='left l2'>l2</div>
  <div class='left l3'>l3</div>
  <div class='left l4'>l4</div>
</div>
```

In the example above I have changed the class in, for example, the xth 'left' to 'left lx'. We can then individually style the divs.

You could also use the ":nth-child" selector, as seen below:

```css
.right {
  color: red;
}

.left {
  color: blue;
}

#container div:nth-child(7),
#container div:nth-child(1) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
      <div class='right'>r1</div>
      <div class='right'>r2</div>
      <div class='right'>r3</div>
      <div class='right'>r4</div>
      <div class='left'>l1</div>
      <div class='left'>l2</div>
      <div class='left'>l3</div>
      <div class='left'>l4</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!